# MySQL 1264 (22003): Out of range value for column

Tags: python, mysql

Help guys!!!
I'm having this issue inserting data into MySQL database. I keep getting this error

> Error while connecting to MySQL 1264 (22003): Out of range value for column 'Encours' at row 1
> MySQL connection is closed

I'm executing this python code. what I'm doing is scraping a web page than formatting it to insert it in the Database

```
 rows = []
# loop over results
for result in results:
# find all columns per result
 data = result.find_all('td')
# check that columns have data
 if len(data) == 0:
  continue
 # if len(data)!=0 execute the rest
 ISIN = data[1].getText()
 Libelle = data[2].getText()
 Nominal = normalize('NFKD',data[4].getText()).replace(' ','')
 Encours = normalize('NFKD',data[5].getText()).replace(' ','')
 DerniereEcheance = data[6].getText()
 InterestRate = data[7].getText().replace('%','').replace(',','.')
 nom = int(Nominal)
 enc=Encours.strip()
 date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(DerniereEcheance).strip(), '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
 intRate = float(InterestRate)
 rows.append([ISIN,Libelle,nom,enc,date_time_obj,intRate])
print(rows)

driver.quit()
"""
connection"""
try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                         database='biatfinancialdata',
                                         user='root',
                                         password='root')
    if connection.is_connected():

        cursor = connection.cursor()
        for row in rows:
            sql = "INSERT INTO t_bta (EffectiveDate, ISIN, Libelle, Nominal, Encours,DerniereEcheance,InterestRate) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
            val =(datetime.date.today(),row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5])
            cursor.execute(sql,val)
            print('im here')
            connection.commit()

except Error as e:
    print("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)
finally:
    if (connection.is_connected()):
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

and this is what the variable rows is showing

> [[' TN0008000226 ', 'BTA 6.9% Mai 2022', 1000, '810661000', '2022-05-09', 6.9], [' TN0008000291 ', 'BTA 5,6% Ao�t 2022', 1000, '894875000', '2022-08-11', 5.6], [' TN0008000358 ', 'BTA 5,5% Octobre 2020', 1000, '901050000', '2020-10-14', 5.5], [' TN0008000366 ', 'BTA 6% Avril 2024', 1000, '628500000', '2024-04-10', 6.0], [' TN0008000564 ', 'BTA 5,75% Janvier 2021', 1000, '700490000', '2021-01-13', 5.75], [' TN0008000572 ', 'BTA 6% Avril 2023', 1000, '953100000', '2023-04-13', 6.0], [' TN0008000580 ', 'BTA 6,3% Octobre 2026', 1000, '817500000', '2026-10-14', 6.3], [' TN0008000606 ', 'BTA 6,7% Avril 2028', 1000, '833687000', '2028-04-13', 6.7], [' TN0008000598 ', 'BTA 6% Janvier 2024', 1000, '383416000', '2024-01-12', 6.0], [' TN0008000614 ', 'BTA 6% F�vrier 2022', 1000, '808155000', '2022-02-11', 6.0], [' TN0008000226 ', 'BTA 6.9% Mai 2022', 1000, '810661000', '2022-05-09', 6.9], [' TN0008000291 ', 'BTA 5,6% Ao�t 2022', 1000, '894875000', '2022-08-11', 5.6], [' TN0008000358 ', 'BTA 5,5% Octobre 2020', 1000, '901050000', '2020-10-14', 5.5], [' TN0008000366 ', 'BTA 6% Avril 2024', 1000, '628500000', '2024-04-10', 6.0], [' TN0008000564 ', 'BTA 5,75% Janvier 2021', 1000, '700490000', '2021-01-13', 5.75], [' TN0008000572 ', 'BTA 6% Avril 2023', 1000, '953100000', '2023-04-13', 6.0], [' TN0008000580 ', 'BTA 6,3% Octobre 2026', 1000, '817500000', '2026-10-14', 6.3], [' TN0008000606 ', 'BTA 6,7% Avril 2028', 1000, '833687000', '2028-04-13', 6.7], [' TN0008000598 ', 'BTA 6% Janvier 2024', 1000, '383416000', '2024-01-12', 6.0], [' TN0008000614 ', 'BTA 6% F�vrier 2022', 1000, '808155000', '2022-02-11', 6.0]]

the T_btc table structure is
[image: T_btc data structure]
I've tried switching the column type from char to varchar to Decimal to Int to bigInt and still getting the same issue. I've checked all the forums and questions posted on this platform and tried the suggested solution. Yet, nothing seems to work here.
Help please!!!

Comment: why did you didn't show us the tbale an especially what Encours is for a datataype it nmust be bog enough to receive 808155000

Comment: @nbk I've just edited my question. I switched the type of Encours from decimal to int then Bigint and at the end, I put it as varchar. Nothing works

Comment: please add a counter to your for loop and see which line throws an error and zhen  check the data of that row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error usually happens when trying to place a value greater than allowed for the variable type specs of a column. You do not mentioned witch column is originating the error but we can assume that it is a varchar field type and, apparently, somehow you are exceeding the allotted length. Check the input values and the table columns specs.
This error occurs on every field type. You may want to check [https://www.thetopsites.net/article/53585870.shtml#:~:text=The%20value%203172978990%20is%20greater,for%20INT%20%E2%80%93%20hence%20the%20error](https://www.thetopsites.net/article/53585870.shtml#:%7E:text=The%20value%203172978990%20is%20greater,for%20INT%20%E2%80%93%20hence%20the%20error). and/or https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.h